# data structure> queue : why is (rear = front) the condition for being empty?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, queue

I know that in circular queue we have [0 , n-1] then [n] will be at the place of [0] again. if we have it using arrays, then pointer to A[n-1] should be increased by one to give pointer to A[0].

a normal queue like this :

|_ empty1_|_ empty2_|_ empty3_|_ empty4_|...

so the "front" points to "empty1" in here. but,

**first question** : where does rear point to when queue is empty?

**second question** : where does rear point to when queue at cell "empty1" contains one element? (*1)

PS: I read some where that empty linear queue means rear=-1 and front=0, and queue with one cell filled means rear=front=0; but then in some pseudo codes I have seen if(front=rear) ->queue is full. so what is this?! array cells are ordered by numbers 0 to n-1, so consequently rear=front=0 has one cell filled, the cell that they both are pointing to. (right?)

---

In circular queues, the statement {rear=front} indicates that the queue is empty and for a full queue we have : rear=n-1 ,front=0 ,rear+1=front=0=n.

---

(*1) : my **third question** is same as the 2nd, but for circulars.

Answer (score 0):

Find the answers to all your questions here below.

1. When the queue is empty you rear also points to the first null Node as your front Node does.

Now for 2nd and 3rd doubt, I will give you a combined reply, so I will tell you my logic which I follow in terms of implementing queues and I hope it will help you to create your own logic for 
queue data structure.

So with me I make use of queue when I want some functionality like FIFO(First IN First OUT). Now if I take array as my storage DS, so let's say I have n as the size for my array A.
So when I insert an element then I will make the rear = rear + 1. So my front still points to 0 and my rear keeps on incrementing based on my insert operation. Now my Array will be full as soon as my 
rear == n.

To check if it's empty, so when we have one element inside of our array, at that moment we will have front and rear = 0, so when we remove another element, make both front and rear = -1. Now next time when we insert our first element then that time we can make front and back as 0 and go on with changing the value of rear as per our operations.

Again, I am saying this is my approach, I change it based on my requirements and usage. Hope this helps :)